# sequentially running command with script in Package.json not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg, package.json

I'm trying to create a script to remove `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` and install everything from scratch using `"reinstall": "rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock && yarn install"` but is not working as expected, I get the following output:

[image]

On the other hand if I run `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock && yarn install` explicitly in the *terminal* it works perfectly.

Is there something wrong in the script? Any idea?

Comment: As the error points out yarn cannot find the package `@koerber-internal\fintl-cli`. Verify is it the correct package name, that has to be included. If its the correct package, them chances are this package was removed from the yarn registry.

Comment: @AbhishekGowda28 thanks for your answer.

Besides the yarn registry thing..., how's posible that if I type `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock && yarn install` in the Terminal it works but not using the script?

Comment: Executed the above command as a script. Its working fine. Can you verify by removing the package and running the script again. You can use error file generated for debug and check why this is happening.